# How to generate a new CRMService.cs file?

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011

I inherited a solution that is using a generated CRMService.cs file.  This file has become out of date as entities have been updated and expanded.  How do I generate an updated file?  I have looked in the SDK and could not easily find the tool I needed.

Comment: Q: Have you tried [CrmSvcUtil](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff681561.aspx)?  Or perhaps you can simply [use the updated WSDL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc151015.aspx)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to use the [CrmSvcUtil](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg327844.aspx):

Comment: I generated a file with the utility you mentioned.  It appears to be in a different format than the file I am trying to replace.  I am trying to use it but updating the using statements in the file brings my 8 core, 24Gb memory server to a halt.  My previous file says "// This source code was auto-generated by wsdl, Version=4.0.30319.1."  The new file does not say this.

Comment: I'm guessing that the old file was created via the old CRM 4 WebReference.  Use @paulsm4's link in your comments to generate the file if you want the same format.  I won't work for some versions of CRM online though...

Answer (score 0):

Although Daryl has a correct answer, the program I was looking for ended up being [wsdl.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7h3ystb6%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)